# Parse polish date with time to ISO format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I have date `14.05.2017 15:32` its polish format of date and time `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` when im using moment library with locales it always set time to default value of `00:00:00`.

Here is example code that i've tried to use 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qju5yhuk/)

```js
console.log(moment('14.05.2017 15:32').format('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Any other suggestions how to parse it?
Expected result:

```
2017-05-14T15:32:00.004Z
```

Comment: Please post code here as a runnable snippet, not elsewhere. External libraries can be included. "pl" is a language code, not a format. You should not base the format on the language since there are many formats that are unrelated to language (and vice versa). You are also ignoring warnings about how you're parsing the string. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: A string without a timezone will be treated as local. The only case where '14.05.2017 15:32' will convert to '2017-05-14T15:32:00.004Z' is where the host timezone offset is +0000.

Comment: Why did not you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the 'pl' argument with the explicit format to parse and add the argument to the format method to display it in the same format:

```
moment('14.05.2017 15:32','DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/s56natsj/1/)

Comment: yep it works now, but how to do it without directly entering the format because it can change as you change the language of the site

Comment: You can try to set moment.locale('pl'); and at the next row momen(...) with the first argument only

Comment: @Wojna—you can't do that as you can't determine the format from the site (client?) language.